# Problem creating my own wallet with multiple accounts

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, transactions, blockchain

I have a local blockchain where I have deployed a contract. I want to interact with it sending multiple responses at the same time. For this propose, I cannot use Metamask to confirm each transaction. I need to create my own wallet and send the tx signed. I have my own wallet with an account using `ethers.js`:

```
var password = "xxxx";
var json = JSON.stringify(data); //data = content of the keystore file of an account
ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet(json, password).then(function(wallet) {
    App.Wallet = wallet;
    App.Wallet.provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(`http://localhost:3002`, { chainId: 15 });
});

var account = App.Wallet.address;
let rawtx = {from: App.Wallet.address, to: App.contracts.MyContract.address, gasPrice: 18000000000, gasLimit: 20000000000, data: getdata }

var signedTransaction = App.Wallet.sign(rawtx);
var transaction = ethers.Wallet.parseTransaction(signedTransaction);
var sendTransactionPromise = App.Wallet.sendTransaction(transaction);
sendTransactionPromise.then(function(transactionHash) { console.log(transactionHash); });
```

It works, but just with one account. Is there any way to create a wallet with multiple accounts? or how could I send multiple transactions from different accounts with my own wallet?

I am trying just with a for, but it is a bit dirty and my browser is not responding correctly, each time that i call `ethers.Wallet.fromEncryptedWallet` for each account the program is broked. I am also trying with `web3.eth.accounts.wallet` but I always get the error "undefined" and I am using web3 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to have multiple wallets if you open different wallets.

One option to imporve performance is to create your own wallets from a mnemonic. Having to decrypt a wallet might make your browser to appear unresponsive.

Other option is to execute from Node in the command line. Node can access to native libraries accelerating some crypto operations.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. Do you know where can I find an example how to use or good documentation about mnemonic? @Ismael

Comment: The definition how to generate mnemonics is in [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). There's a package [bip39](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bip39) for npm that can be used to generate mnemonic phrases.